# Javascript Forcing Load on Title

Tags: javascript, jquery

all
I am wonder if it is possible to use javascript or html to make a spinner on the header when a button is clicked.

I am using the $.ajax function and everytime it post a request to a php url, I am hoping that it the header would spin. See Image attached to see what spinner I mean[image]

Comment: That is commonly referred to as an Ajax progress spinner, which is quite easy to do. However, you are going to have a challenge trying to get it to work in the tabs of multiple browsers.

Comment: Aside from the possibility of this: are you sure this is what you want? The spinner in the tab indicates a page refresh, that's not what AJAX is though. It would be less ambiguous if you'd create a spinner on a button or some sort of progress bar.

Comment: What would be best recommended way when posting an ajax? In order to indicate the user that there is something going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my page</title>
    <link id="my_ico" rel="icon" href="path to your ico image">
  </head>
</html>
```

then you can change the ico path on ajax load

```
$.ajax({
  url: "something",
  before: function(){
    $('#my_ico').attr('href', "path to spinner image");
  }
  # the rest of your ajax params
});
```

I would warn that this isn't really ideal behavior as it is disingenuous to indicate to the user that the page is reloading when it actually is not.

Comment: What would be the best way to tell a user that an ajax request is being sent?

Comment: @user288231 a loading gif on or near the element clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something else to look at. spin.js is a ighly configurable spinner that doesn't use any images, or external CSS.

http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

It might be overkill for what you are trying to achieve, but at least it is worth a look.